# fluid image behavior on Google Ads images

Tags: responsive-design, ads, fluid-layout

I want to add the [fluid image behavior](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/) to the image displayed by the ad (Google Ads) on my site, ¿how can do this? the ad seems that is a remote content pulled by an iframe, so the Same Origin Policy "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy" applies to the case of add the fluid behavior to the image (or I am wrong?), but I am not sure, so I am here on SO asking about that.